# I have snowflake-snowpark-python 1.4.0 installed in Snowflake (as in "packages" view), but getting version as 1.0.0 from snowpark procedure (python)

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using explode() function in my snowpark(Python) procedure. This function was introduced in snowflake-snowpark-python library in version 1.4.0 (in April, 2023). I checked in the “Packages” view in Snowflake, and confirmed that this version is available. So, I installed the same version in my local development environment (VS code) for implementation. Later, when I ported the python program back to Snowflake as stored procedure, it was found that, Snowflake is taking version 1.0.0 as default, and hence is throwing error on the explode() function.

Attaching a screenshot for details. Would you be able to help me with this?
[Snowflake version Issue:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWFfG.png)

Comment: just to confirm. You opened UI, created a new Python worksheet and run the code to get the Snowpark Version and it returned 1.0.0?

Comment: Yes, correct - as you see in the screenshot. I was expecting to get 1.4.0 as shown in the "installed packages" list. I need 1.4.0 version, because in my actual procedure, I am using explode() method, which is supported from version 1.4.0 onwards.

Comment: Try to shutdown/start the warehouse or otherwise try to use a different warehouse as a test.